# Java nested loop issue with switch statement

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

For case "1" it seems to just loop instead of jumping to `drunkSong();`.  If the user selects case "2" it will work fine and ask the user to input the number to return the int "BeerNum".

Case "1" needs to accept a default value of 99 while Case "2" needs to accept user input.

I have attached the code,  if you can point my mistake out or where I have gone wrong.

```
package PartOne;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class View {

    public void begin() {
        BeerSong.drunkSong();
    }

    private int setBeerNum() {
        return beerNum;
    }

    private int beerNum;

    public Integer Menu() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        // print menu
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ". Menu item #" + i);

        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        // handle user commands
        boolean quit = false;
        int menuItem;
        do {
            System.out.print("Choose menu item: ");
            menuItem = in.nextInt();
            switch (menuItem) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Default ");
                    begin();
                    while (true)
                        try {
                            //where I have made a mistake
                            beerNum = 99;
                            this.beerNum = setBeerNum();
                            break;

                        } catch (NumberFormatException BecauseIsaidSo) {
                            System.out.print("Try again: ");
                        }

                    //working
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Enter your number to play the song: ");
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                    while (true)
                        try {
                            beerNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                            this.beerNum =  setBeerNum();
                            return beerNum;

                        } catch (NumberFormatException BecauseIsaidSo) {
                            System.out.print("Try again: ");
                        }
                case 0:
                    quit = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
            }
        }
        while (!quit) ;
        System.out.println("Bye-bye!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding the break; for each case?

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar That won't make the slightest bit of difference.

Comment: What does `drunkSong` do? Also, you should use constants or enums for your switch case. `setBeerNum` is also a pretty weird name for a getter. You can work on readability for this code, clean code is the first step to bug-free code.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't compile: `setBeerNum()` doesn't match the correct signature. Can you provide actually compilable and executable code?

Comment: Corrected the compile issue, copy and paste error, apologies. I was not expecting responses for a while and I thought I would have time to tidy it up. Sorry first post.

Comment: drunkSong() points to another class and works out the program 99 bottles of beer on the wall. I can put that code up if you wish.

Comment: @Draken6264 thanks for the edit. The only reason I could see your code to loop over `drunkSong` is if `drunkSong` was recursive. Do you know how to use a debugger and breakpoints?

Comment: Honestly not yet, I have only started with Java about a month ago and still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is much better to encapsulate menu logic in the separate class and encapsulate all logic in it. Moreover, logic for each menu item should be encapsulated in separate method as well.

```
public final class Menu {

    private Integer res;
    private boolean quit;

    public static Integer showMenuAndGetResult() {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.activate();
        return menu.res;
    }

    private Menu() {
    }

    private void activate() {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            show();

            while (!quit) {
                System.out.print("Choose menu item: ");
                int menuItem = in.nextInt();

                if (menuItem == 1)
                    onMenuItem1(in);
                else if (menuItem == 2)
                    onMenuItem2(in);
                else if (menuItem == 0)
                    onMenuQuit();
                else
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
            }

            System.out.println("Bye-bye!");
        }
    }

    private void show() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ". Menu item #" + i);

        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void onMenuItem1(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Default ");
        // TODO menu 1 logic incapsulation
    }

    private void onMenuItem2(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter your number to play the song: ");
        // TODO menu 2 logic incapsulation
    }

    private void onMenuQuit() {
        res = null;
        quit = true;
    }

}
```

**P.S.** I personally try to avoid using `switch`. This is not my recomendation, just note. I think that if...else if is more readable and problemless.

Comment: Although true, doesn't seem to be answering the question on why the code isn't behaving as expected

Comment: @Dici For some code it is better to offer more sutiable solution than find a problem. It is better for requester as well, because his code is not optimal. Probably reformat a code, requester find a problem itself.

Comment: Yes that's why I suggested a few clean-ups in a comment but I don't think that makes it an answer. Different opinions I guess :)

Comment: Hey All, thanks for your help. @oleg, Your method worked thank you. Here is the link to it in Github: https://github.com/Draken62/Java-Project/blob/master/src/PartOne/View.java

Comment: Does anyone know, how I can resolve this answer as resolved ?